# NF-e Delphi. Função RecepcionarLoteRpsSincrono

Tags: delphi, nfe

Não tenho experiência nessa área de NFe. Fui orientado pelo suporte como testes iniciais a utilizar a função:

```
RecepcionarLoteRpsSincrono(const nfseCabeMsg: WideString; const nfseDadosMsg: WideString): 
  WideString;
```

Minha dúvida no momento é qual o parâmetro das WideString devo passar, um exemplo qualquer para teste.

Tipo:
nfseCabeMsg := 'xyz';
nfseDadosMsg := 'abc';

Assim passar como parâmetros da função. Os exemplos que eu tenho são os XML completos mas já que devo usar a função preciso saber qual trecho que passo para cada parâmetro.

Comment: Essa função é de algum componente que você usa? Tem como postar a função completa?

Comment: É o Delphi consumindo um Web Server NFe. As funções são do Web Server.